# Исключение «не найдено» в роуте Laravel

Tags: laravel

Не смог найти в сети примера как в такой роут добавить исключение, чтобы если ID не найден выдавало 404 ошибку.

Доки читал, но так и не понял как мне нужно изменить мой роут.

Сейчас у меня роут такой

```
Route::get('/post/{id}', 'PostModelController@getOne')->where('id', '\d+');
```

Мой контроллер

```
   <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostModelController extends Controller
{
    public function post($order = 'date', $dir = '')
    {
        if($dir=='desc'){
            $posts = Post::all()->sortByDesc($order);
        }else{
            $posts = Post::all()->sortBy($order);
        }
        return view('test.post', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }
    public function getOne(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id)->findOrFail($id);
        return view('test.postOne', ['post' => $post]);
    }
}
```

сейчас если ввести неверный id - ошибка

> Error
> Call to a member function findOrFail() on null

Answer (score 1):

Ответ `404` Вы можете реализовать в методе `getOne()` в контроллере `PostModelController`:

```html
public function getOne(Request $request, $id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
}
```

Comment: Переписал так $postModel = PostModelController::findOrFail($id); так как не совсем понял почему просто PostModel:: ,  но получаю ошибку BadMethodCallException Method App\Http\Controllers\PostModelController::findOrFail does not exist. Пробовал и как вы написали, но пишет что класс PostModel не найден.

Comment: Вы до редакции Вашего вопроса, написали, что контроллер PostModelController, отсюда, по понятиям Laravel, я предположил, что у Вас модель - PostModel. Вам следует использовать Вашу модель, разумеется. findOrFail является методом абстрактного класса Model, которую вы наследуете, поэтому он будет работать с любой моделью.

Answer (score 0):

Понял как сделать -

```
    public function getOne($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    return view('test.postOne', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

т.е. вместо

```
$post = Post::find($id)->findOrFail($id);
```

как я думал нужно

```
$post = Post::findOrFail($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное самое простое в вашей ситуации правильно именовать роуты что бы лара сама спарсила и забиндила роут

`Route::get('post/{post}', 'PostModelController@getOne');`

И в самом контроллере

```
public function getOne(Request $request, Post $post)
{
/// some actions
}
```

И теперь лара сама поищет вашу модель